# Get registry info regarding where dependencies are coming from

Tags: go, go-modules, go-toolchain

I would like to get my dependencies from a private golang registry.

By using `GOPROXY`.

I would like to make sure all dependencies are coming from that private registry.

The only way I found for now is by doing

```
go get -v -t  github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go@fakeversion
```

Which will return

```
go get: github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go@fakeversion: invalid version: reading  http://myprivateregistry.com 404 Not found
```

How can I get the registry it's taken from without doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trace `go get` with `go get -v -x <package>` (can omit `-v`) and check that the requests match your expectations:

```
$ go get -v -x
# get https://myinternalproxy.com/github.com/@v/list
# get https://myinternalproxy.com/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/@v/list
# get https://myinternalproxy.com/github.com/gin-gonic/@v/list
# get https://myinternalproxy.com/github.com/stretchr/testify/require/@v/list
# get https://myinternalproxy.com/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert/@v/list
# get https://myinternalproxy.com/github.com/stretchr/testify/@v/list
# get https://myinternalproxy.com/github.com/stretchr/@v/list
# get https://myinternalproxy.com/github.com/stretchr/@v/list: 410 Gone (0.462s)
# get https://myinternalproxy.com/github.com/gin-gonic/@v/list: 410 Gone (0.466s)
# get https://myinternalproxy.com/github.com/@v/list: 410 Gone (0.466s)
... much more logs
```